# Trouble using Html.dropDownList() in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this function that returns the type  `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
        {


            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> results = null;

            results =*(some logic)*


            return results;
        }
```

I try to bind this to dropdown in a view using

```
 <% foreach (IEnumerable<SelectListItem> schdItem in Model.GetItems())
{%>

       <%= Html.DropDownList("xxx", schdItem)%>

<%} %>
```

But it breaks with the error message

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.
```

How do I fix this?

Based on the comment from asawyer I modified it to

```
  <%= Html.DropDownList("xxx", Model.GetScheduleItems())%>
```

now it works!

Comment: Your trying to create a select element for each select list **item**, rather then once for the collection!

Comment: @asawyer...you just answered my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No loop needed, just this.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("xxx", Model.GetItems())%>
```

I would make the `SelectList` a property on your model rather than a getter method.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("xxx", Model.MySelectList)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("xxx", Model.GetItems())%>
```

Althought this is a terrible way to go about it.  Instead, you should be using Html.DropDownListFor such as this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(Model.SelectedItem, Model.Items) %>
```

Where Model.SelectedItem is the type of item, and Model.Items is a property that returns a collection of SelectListItems.